# Hibernate with parameter values

Tags: grails, log4j

I am using grails 1.3.9 and in my log4j file I have set the following properties:

```
debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
trace 'org.hibernate.type'
```

But still I am not getting parameter values from the sql queries only question marks  in my console? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure? You will see your query with question marks. The parameters will be before or after the query, because `org.hibernate.type` will show them.

Comment: Check you `logging` level. If it is set to `info` on the `root` you wont be able to see `debug` logs.